# In JSP, how to output "<br/>"

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have a string var in my Struts2 action, like this:

```
String tmp = "<br/>";
```

I want to print it out to the html page as HTML tag by JSP, like this:

```
<s:property value="tmp"/>
```

But, in the html page, the `<` and `>` was translated to `&lt;` and `&gt;` which i don't want to.

So how should I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`<s:property>` has an `escape` attribute [which determines if the value is HTML-escaped](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/docs/property.html). The default is `true`, so that's why your `<br/>` is being escaped.

So you can do something like this:

```
<s:property value="tmp" escape="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use JSTL then the c:out tag has an escapeXml attribute you can set to false.

Comment: He's not, though, he's using Struts2, not JSTL.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just using OGNL:

```
${tmp}
```

For more information visit the [docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.2/docs/ognl.html) page