# printing string as html components in struts

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2, web, struts

i am putting `<input type="text" name="Job Name" value=""/>` inside `private List<String> dataFields;` and iterate it in my jsp page with struts like :

> ```
> <logic:iterate name="dataFields" id="dataFieldsId">
> <p>
>   List Messages <bean:write name="dataFieldsId"/>
> </p>
> </logic:iterate>
> ```

but my browser instead of showing me a input box, it prints me the exact `String` that i have put in my action class, i mean this : `<input type="text" name="Job Name" value=""/>`  what can i do to solve this?

edit ---------
actually the above syntax is for struts 1, i changed my iterator to struts 2 and the code now is :

> ```
> <s:iterator  value="dataFields"  var="dataFieldsId">
> <p>
>   <s:property escapeHtml="false" value="dataFieldsId" />
> </p>
> </s:iterator>
> ```

and it is working like a charm

Comment: have you tried this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952815/in-jsp-how-to-output-br??

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza: The question is tagged Struts 2 but the code looks like Struts 1.

Comment: @dave: Please retag the question with the proper Struts version. It will be easier for others that see it.

Comment: my libraries are struts 2! and i am using struts 2

Comment: I don't understand. The logic and bean tags are struts 1. You might want to start by figuring out what you're actually using.

Comment: i am using struts 2 core, but i guess also struts 1.3 taglib

Comment: <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
   <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.8</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: so what should i use instead of bean??

Comment: Why are you even generating HTML outside of a JSP or custom tag? I don't see a need to do it on this case, either.

Comment: @dave newton : to generate dynamic html forms each has different fields of data, this is the best solution that i came up, let me know if you suggest e better one because mine is very complicated

Comment: @dave It totally depends on the nature of the fields. If they're just input tags all you need is a list of names and values; the HTML can be generated in the JSP. If they're of various types, it's less-clear what the best option would be w/o knowing more.

Comment: @newton different types and also dynamic , by dynamic i mean user can generate different types later in program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the value is filtered for HTML characters and they are replaced by their entity equivalents. [Try the `filter` attribute](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-bean.html#write) like so:

```
<bean:write name="dataFieldsId" filter="false" />
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this problem in my past project.
Please, try this like the following :

```
<logic:iterate name="dataFields" id="dataFieldsId">
<p>
List Messages <input type="text" name="Job Name" value="<bean:write name="dataFieldsId""/>
</p>
</logic:iterate>
```

Comment: Did you even look at your answer after posting it?